# how can i sort this table by another field that not part of the groups?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

how can i sort this table by another field that not part of the groups?

[image]

Comment: You can now only sort inside group 3. The other sorting is given by the groups. Maybe there's a solution for your specific situation, but here is not enough detail to answer...

Comment: Hi,
which details are you need to know more?